# Digispark Rev.3 Kickstarter ATTiny85 using all 6 pins

Tags: i2c, attiny, attiny85, stepper-motor

i have some trouble to use i2c and the other pins at the same time.

im tring to control the attiny over i2c with a arduino and the attiny should control a 28byj-48 stepmotor.

i started to setup the i2c connection pin 0 and pin 2 is use for that. it is working fine but then i connected the stepmotor driver on pin 1,3,4,5 after connecting the 5 pin i lose my i2c connection.

here is the code from the attiny, nothing special

```
#include <TinyWireS.h>                // wrapper class for I2C slave routines

#define I2C_SLAVE_ADDR  0x29            // i2c slave address (38)
#define A 1
#define B 3
#define C 4
#define D 5
#define NUMBER_OF_STEPS_PER_REV 512


void setup(){
  pinMode(1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
  TinyWireS.begin(I2C_SLAVE_ADDR);      // init I2C Slave mode
}


void loop(){
  byte byteRcvd = 0;
  if (TinyWireS.available()){           // got I2C input!
    byteRcvd = TinyWireS.receive();     // get the byte from master
    //Blink(byteRcvd);           // master must wait for this to finish before calling Wire.requestFrom
    //byteRcvd += 10;                                                    // add 10 to what's received
    //TinyWireS.send(byteRcvd);           // send it back to master

    //             Blink(1);                  // show we transmitted
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such Digispark board as the Rev 3. There was going to be, but there was a mistake, so they went straight from Rev 2 to Rev 4. However unscrupulous Chinese counterfeiters are making "Rev 3" boards.

So... your mileage may vary since the components used on there could be of *any* dubious quality.

But to your problem: P5 is also the RESET pin.  If the fuses on that chip are set correctly then it can be used as an IO port. But being a counterfeit, who knows what they set the fuses to?

But if you *do* change the fuses you will have to rely on the power-on reset (plugging it in) to trigger uploads.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to [Majenko](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/4143/majenko)'s answer I can report having used many of the "Rev.3" counterfeits, every single one came with *chip default fuses* thereby **reset enabled**.

You can set the [RSTDISBL](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf#G1.2073549) fuse with your [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/ArduinoISP), plus update the [micronucleus](https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus) bootloader in the process (freeing 0.4k).

Keep in mind setting this fuse will **disable ISP programming**, so you will need a working bootloader to reprogram the chip unless you revert it via [HV programming](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-unlock-Digispark-ATtiny85-and-convert-it-to/).